# How to manually link posts to each other in Wordpress

Tags: posts, multi-language, plugin-polylang

I have two language versions for each of my pages using Polylang plugin. There's a language switcher on every page. But somehow I created two posts not connected to each other (first two in the list). How can I interconnect them so language switcher works properly?

[image: screenshot from Posts window]

Comment: It's not really the solution, but more of a workaround. I would just create a new post and translation, copy the content and delete the old two separate posts. Problem solved.

Answer (score 12):

I'll use as example two pages: `Hello` (en) and `Bonjour` (fr).

1. Click "Edit" in page `Hello` (doesn't really matter which one)
2. At the right sidebar there will be the language of the current page (English) and a list of flags of other languages with a plus symbol (to create another page) and a text input beside it: [image: Sample page]
3. In this text input, start typing the page title of the translated page (on our example, `Bonjour`). The input will suggest the other page, just click on it and save, it will link each other.

[Source](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/setting-up-a-wordpress-multilingual-site-with-polylang/translating-posts-or-pages/)

Comment: this will also work for categories and tags

Answer (score 1):

**[pll_save_term_translations](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/)**
Defines which terms are translations of each other
Usage:

```
pll_save_term_translations($arr);
```

‘$arr’ => (required) associative array of translations with language code as key and term id as value

https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the language for all existing categories and post tags, otherwise they won’t be displayed in the autocomplete input field.

[Source](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/setting-up-a-wordpress-multilingual-site-with-polylang/translating-categories-or-post-tags/)